# Uploading a photo with PHP and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, photo

I want to have a single button that when clicked opens a file dialogue, and then after the user selects the photo they want to upload and the dialogue closes. I want the photo to upload. I cant think of a way of doing this because in the form you cant use both the `type = file` and `type = submit` together. Would I need to use jquery to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: And what if the user clicks the wrong file by accident, I wouldn't consider this good userbility.

Comment: It might be a good idea to still have a two-stage approach to the upload, here.  The traditional: 1) user finds file 2) user clicks button to upload.  It gives the user a chance to make sure he or she wants to really upload the file(s).  I edited my answer below to better reflect what you were asking; sorry about my initial answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the idea is to use jQuery for the inital part of having a user pick a file to upload... and then some sort of other, server-side language (like PHP,) will actually do the heavy lifting (by actually uploading the file.)

Here's a jQuery plugin that helps you do this:
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

**EDIT:**
Yes, I believe with jQuery (or some other library... or plugin,) it would be possible to have an event listener (or something,) pick up when a user browses for a file to upload... and automatically starts to upload it once the file has been chosen.  But, again, as was said earlier, it's probably safer to take a two-step approach to file uploads for now.

Comment: The blueimp File Uploader is awesome.  I have used modified versions of it in at least a dozen different projects.  The fact that it doesn't use flash pushes it past all other uploaders.

Answer (score 1):

try [this](http://code.google.com/p/ocupload/)

> One-Click Upload is a jQuery plugin that replaces the standard file
>   input element, allowing you to use any link, image or element to be
>   used for the purpose of bringing up the "file browse" dialogue. It
>   completes the upload behind the scenes without refreshing the page,
>   making it less obtrusive and easier to style than a standard upload
>   form.

Answer (score 1):

To get the upload started the way you describe you will need to use JavaScript. jQuery is a very good library to use to make that process easier, but it is not required.